# Add logo to CC Library with exclusion zones

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, logo, creative-cloud, adobe-library

I've been using the CC Library to speed up my work flow but one thing that stumps me is adding logo graphics with the necessary exclusion zones around it. I'd much rather be using the vectors directly rather than having to import PNG files each time I use the logo for a presentation.

Whenever I drag the graphic, only the object is added to the CC Library (naturally). I've tried dragging the artboard as well, but only the artboard is added (without the object).

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Below your logo, insert a fully transparent rectangle in Illustrator. It will add apace around it, but visually the logo stays as is. The growth of the file size is minimal and you can remove the rectangle or resize it as needed.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works perfectly on Illustrator! However on InDesign, the graphic still just appears with its own bounds.

Comment: @JulianO when "placing" in InDesign, show options ... and choose "Trim" or "Media" for the placement options. That will place the file in Indesign based on the *artboard* size, not the artwork.